# I have added side menu in iOS app, but menu appearing in black color

Tags: ios, swift, side-menu

I have added side menu using this [iOS Library](https://github.com/jonkykong/SideMenu) by code implementation. Below code written in view did load func:

```
let menuRightNavigationController = UISideMenuNavigationController(rootViewController: SideMenuViewController())

SideMenuManager.default.menuRightNavigationController = menuRightNavigationController
SideMenuManager.default.menuFadeStatusBar = false
```

And below one written in button action:

```
present(SideMenuManager.default.menuRightNavigationController!, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Result screenshot attached below:

[image: Click here for screenshot]

Comment: Hi I'm using the same library for my current project, how are you defining the view for `SideMenuViewController()` ? is it via .storyboard, or is it via .xib?

Comment: Thanks @CoderFrom94 for replying I was using ViewController in RootViewController instead of TableViewController, its working fine now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you added the TableViewController which is inside RootViewController of SideMenu with code, you can give `tableView.backgroundColor = .white` at `viewDidLoad` function. Probably you are initializing SideMenu without any configuration.

Default TableViewController shows black background.

Comment: Thanks man, you've made my day. I was using ViewController instead of TableViewController, now tableview is appearing in my side menu.

Comment: You are very welcome. Enjoy using the library. @Huzaifaameen